# Why does the Y axis change in population density plot when changing from raw scores to z-scores (assuming normal distribution)

Tags: density-function, z-score

Why do values on the Y-axis change in a probability density plot when changing from raw values to z-scores?

The mean z-score aligns with 0.40 on the Y-axis, while the Y-value for the mean with respect to raw values is much lower. Why is that?

Here is some sample code in R:

x=seq(25,500,length=200)
meanx = mean(x)
sdx = sd(x)

y1 = dnorm(x, mean = meanx, sd = sdx )

plot(x,y1,type="l", col="red")

xz = (x - meanx)/sdx

y2 = dnorm(xz, mean = 0, sd = 1)

plot(xz, y2, type="l", col = "red")